# Unable to push local migrations to Supabase through CLI

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I tried to push the local migrations to the supabase database through its cli with the command `supabase db push`. The error it is showing me is:

`Error: ERROR: must be owner of table users (SQLSTATE 42501)`

I had set up the cli with `supabase db remote set 'postgresql://postgres:<your_password>@db.<your_project_ref>.supabase.co:5432/postgres'` as per the ReadME in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/supabase/cli/tree/main/examples/tour).

Can I get some help on how to push my local changes?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem right now. Did you solved this after a month?

Comment: Nope...I just gave up on supabase local

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if you have tables created from the dashboard. To resolve it manually, you can run this on the SQL editor:

```
alter table users owner to postgres;
```

We (Supabase) are making changes to the platform so you won't have to do these steps manually.

See also: https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/128